# magento2.4 customer login

Tags: customer, magento2.4, login, redirect

My Magento 2.4 Customer login redirects to customer login again and not login. also my list page doesn't show any product I Use all commands like reindex but not show and I need to solve these two issues

Comment: you are in local or server?

Comment: no i just prepare a server for development

Answer (score 0):

**1.Login Issue**

Please use **https://** instead of **http://** for fix login issue.

**2.Product Visiblity Issue**

1. Check product **enable** or not
2. Assign product to **websites**
3. Assign product to **categories**
4. Change product **stock status** to in stock
5. Check product **visibility config**
6. Reindex and flush cache

Also check the Store View level.

I hope it works

Comment: Thanks, what about list pages?

Comment: u configured elasticsearch properly?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I am. but if you need any file please let me know